# Setup SaaS based application with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I needed a help, the problem i'm facing is. 
Assume have a domain like 
*aaa.xyz.com* and other domain like *bbb.xyz.com*.
So when my user tries to login on *aaa.xyz.com* then all the feather operations should work on **aaa** database for that sub-domain respectively if the user logins from *bbb.xyz.com* then **bbb** database should do all the functionality

How do i setup such system using PHP laravel framework

Comment: This is called tenancy and there are packages that do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

> There are different/multiple approaches available to follow, I will mention couple of them:

**First approach** Keep multiple env files for respective domain (containing the database credentials of each domain) and utilze the required one like below (write this code in your bootstrap\app.php right before return $app):

`$envFile = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'aaa.xyz.com' ? '.env-aaa' : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'bbb.xyz.com' ? '.env-bbb';
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);`

> You can also create groups of routes in the web.php/routes.php file like below to keep the code clean:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.domain.com'], function(){
...
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'mobile.domain.com'], function(){
//...
});
```

**Second approach** (if you have more than 2 domains or you expect to add more domains in future)
Here are the steps:

1. Create a parent database and create a table containing credentials of all the domains along with the domain name.
2. When a domain is hit, check in the parent database the existence of that url and fetch the credentials in your project and keep in the session in the encrypted form and pass them to your database.php file.
   Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Ill try with the 1st approach and see. 
Second approach i don't feel is a good way to implement this.

Even there can be better approaches then this.